# Number-sequence puzzle

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Here's a number sequence puzzle on INSC-2017:

```
132, 2646, 2128128, ?, 8482124821221022.5
```

I managed to get some progress but don't know how to complete it (progress deleted as comment request).

Comment: I suggest not including your progress, whether it be in spoiler tags/quotes or not. Let us solve it as it is (and trust me, one of us will, but not me, probably)! :D

Comment: @user477343 alright deleted now, good luck!

Comment: Let the fun begin...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is an aberration in the pattern, I believe the number is

> 42416241615.

The pattern is then

> 132, 2646, 2128128, 42416241615, 8482124821221022.5

Reasoning:

> You have to double each number in the previous term and concatenate them. Then calculate the sum of all the digits in the current term and divide it by 2, and concatenate that number to the end.

Namely:

> $2*2||1*2||2*2||8*2||1*2||2*2||8*2|| = 424162416$. Then $\frac{4+2+4+1+6+2+4+1+6}{2} = \frac{30}{2} = 15$, so the term is 42416241615. If we take this number, then $4*2||2*2||4*2||1*2||6*2||2*2||4*2||1*2||6*2||1*2||5*2|| = 84821248212210$. Then $\frac{8+4+8+2+1+2+4+8+2+1+2+2+1+0}{2} = \frac{45}{2} = 22.5$, so the term is 8482124821221022.5.

This works except for

> the random 2 which starts 2128128, which should be a 4 (that term should instead be 4128129, then the next term ought to be 82416241818, and following that 16482124821621622.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive at the next number? I'm not quite sure thanks!

Comment: @simonzack I’ve updated my answer. Funnily enough I think the question from the test isn’t as good as I think it could’ve been, but c’est la vie!

Comment: You're right, you figured out the last part, thanks!